# Throwing Error in Rescue method?

Tags: ruby

I'm New to ruby,learning basics,I want to enter only Integer Values in age field,Need to Throw Not a number when it is a string  when executing the following code

```
puts "Enter Age "

age=Integer(gets) rescue nil

if age.is_a?(Numeric)

puts "Your age is #{age}"

else 

puts "Not a Number"

end

if age>25 

puts "You are Permitted"

else 

puts "Not allowed"

end
```

getting error as **': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)** What am doing wrong ?

Comment: Isn't it always a string? You cannot input anything other than a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `puts "Not a number"` which will print a message but then your program will keep running as usual.  On that line, try replacing "puts" with "raise" and then read about Ruby exceptions.

Comment: Yes i want to catch the exception and Need  to replace with error message .'Raise' Helped me..thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The user input was not in a format to give an integer, so by `rescue`, `age` became `nil`. You tried to apply `>` on it in `if age>25`, which is not defined.

Comment: Yes you got that point ..I need to Catch the Exception and Need to Print the error message ..Now  'puts' Replaced  Raise' works for me ..Thanks for your analysis

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `rescue` to `nil` because you're planning to get and respond to whatever the user inputs and you don't need to `raise` because you don't want the program to exit after the user inputs a non Integer.

This is probably what you need:

```
age = ""
loop do
    puts "Enter Age "
    age = gets.chomp
if age.to_i.to_s == age.to_s
    puts "Your age is #{age}"
else 
    puts "Not a Number"
    next
end

if age.to_i > 25 
    puts "You are Permitted"
    break
else 
    puts "Not allowed"
    break
end
end until age.to_i.to_s == age.to_s
```

`next` will make it go back and do the next loop, and `break` will break out of the loop.
You can use `age.to_i.to_s == age.to_s` to really check if `age` is an integer.

Comment: well, since I cannot ask for clarification to the author due to insufficient reputation, I have to make an assumption. In case the author needs to raise an error when the input is not an integer he can change the `puts` in `puts "Not a Number"` to `raise`.

Comment: when user enters string value it need to throw error message and need to take out of the program..sorry i provided less info ..But you people are talented .. thanks a lot